# Paypal Express Checkout button does not work in Sandbox mode

Tags: javascript, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I copied and pasted the code Paypal has to add a checkout button on our site https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client. In the interactive demo it works perfectly. However, once I run my own html file with the copied code, the box shows up for half a second and it crashes. I am getting a 400 error code.

This is my code:

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

    <script>
        paypal.Button.render({

            env: 'sandbox', // sandbox | production

            //must change to Charle's account
            client: {
                sandbox:    '...',
                production: '...'
            },

            // Show the buyer a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow
            commit: true,

            // payment() is called when the button is clicked
            payment: function(data, actions) {

                // Make a call to the REST api to create the payment
                return actions.payment.create({
                    payment: {
                        transactions: [
                            {
                                amount: { total: '10.0', currency: 'USD' }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            },

            // onAuthorize() is called when the buyer approves the payment
            onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

                // Make a call to the REST api to execute the payment
                return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                    window.alert('Payment Complete!');
                });
            }

        }, '#paypal-button-container');

    </script>
</body>
```

Note: I removed the client IDs for the question. MOST IMPORTANTLY, this works if I change the env to 'production.

Comment: is this working in production with the client ID which you have removed ???

Comment: @RJ-It does work. I mentioned that in the note

Comment: have you created your own application client id ??